# Non-halting regular expressions (python re module)

Tags: python, regex, exit

What can cause non-halting behavior in regular expression match() operation (with Python's re module)?

I'm current wracking my brains trying to work out a problem that has stumped me for hours. Why does the below line hang?

```
re.compile(r'.*?(now|with that|at this time|ready|stop|wrap( it|) up|at this point|happy|pleased|concludes|concluded|we will|like to)(,)*(( |\n)[a-z]+(\'[a-z]+)*,*){0,20}( |\n)(take|for|to|open|entertain|answer|address)(( |\n|)[a-z]+(\'[a-z]+)*,*){0,20}( |\n|)(questions|Q *& *A).*?', re.DOTALL| re.IGNORECASE).match("I would now like to turn the presentation over to your host for today's call, Mr. Mitch Feiger, please proceed.")
```

In short, I'm using match(), the regular expression is `r'.*?(now|with that|at this time|ready|stop|wrap( it|) up|at this point|happy|pleased|concludes|concluded|we will|like to)(,)*(( |\n)[a-z]+(\'[a-z]+)*,*){0,20}( |\n)(take|for|to|open|entertain|answer|address)(( |\n|)[a-z]+(\'[a-z]+)*,*){0,20}( |\n|)(questions|Q *& *A).*?'`

And the text is: `"I would now like to turn the presentation over to your host for today's call, Mr. Mitch Feiger, please proceed."`

I understand my regular expression is a bit of a mess, it's been built over time to somewhat cheatily match paragraphs in which the speakers announces the start of a question session. My main confusion right now is trying to find what in there could be causing what I assume is a non-halting search.

It gets stuck on a lot of other pieces of text my program uses, but far from all of them (the program processes thousands of text files, each with ~100 of these text pieces it needs to do matching on), and I can't see any common factors. To be clear, this is **not** supposed to return a match, but this check does need to be done, and I can't understand why it hangs like it does.

More generally, what are the sorts of things that could cause a Python regular expression match to hang indefinitely? I'd love to have the information so I can work out the problem myself, but at this point, I'd take a cheap answer...

Comment: I recommend you test regex expressions using regex101.com online regular expression tester.  I put your expression in and it reported you have 'catastrophic backtracking'.   I don't want to correct your expression here because you can learn more trying it out yourself.  (It also points you to another url describing Runaway Regular Expressions in detail)

Comment: I already tried this before posting, and can't see any mention of 'catastrophic backtracking'. I also tried this just now and still can't see any mention

Comment: Here's where I did it: [link](https://regex101.com/r/mQau2s/1)

Answer (score 0):

Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCRE), which is what Python's re module uses, are no longer "regular" in the Computer Science sense. Because of this, they can suffer from catastrophic backtracking: https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html

This doesn't help you much with your problem. What would help you is:

1. break down your regexp in multiple small blocks
2. see how long each block takes to execute
3. start putting the blocks together to get closer to your original huge regexp

You might have to stop trying to do everything with 1 single regexp and you might use 1 or 2 and a bit of code to put the 2 parts together more efficiently.

Comment: I've found what causes the issue, it's the last `,*`. `,{0,1}` also causes the same problem. This doesn't cause any issues anywhere else in the regex, and I can't replicate it causing an issue by itself, so I'm very confused as to how such a simple "match 0 or 1 commas" can cause non-halting behaviour

Comment: Removing the last `|` from the second to last `( |\n|)` group also fixes it. This is good, because (unlike the previous find) this symbol is actually completely unnecessary. However, this still provides absolutely no understanding for me